# Cesium toggle 3D buildings on/off

Tags: openstreetmap, 3d, cesium

Does anyone have a working code example of how to toggle 3D buildings on/off in Cesium?

Since the 3D OSM buildings in Cesium are solid, everything beneath them is obscured so I would like to add an option to toggle them on/off.

So far using this to display 3D buildings:

```js
var tileset = viewer.scene.primitives.add(
  new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
    url: Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(97388),
  })
);
```

Idea is to have a checkbox to on/off 3D buildings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `div` with either a [button or a checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) and the action performed on click\change you'll add or remove your layer.

I would first recommend giving the layer a name:

```
var tileset = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
    url: Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(97388),
  })
viewer.scene.primitives.add(tileset);
```

now the action to remove the layer is as simple as:

```
viewer.scene.primitives.remove(tileset);
```

If you would use a checkbox, you would need something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50012963/5874767):

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById('myCheckbox')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    viewer.scene.primitives.add(tileset);
  } else {
    viewer.scene.primitives.remove(tileset);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById('myCheckbox')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    tileset.show = true;
  } else {
    tileset.show = false;
  }
})
```